# Data Table Add Calculated Column Based on ID in Other Column

Tags: r, data.table, data-manipulation

I am having trouble added a column that has it's value based on another column in the same data set.

Here is an example of what I am working with:

```
+----+------+------------+
| id | type |    date    |
+----+------+------------+
|  1 | a    | 2017-08-01 |
|  1 | b    | 2017-08-05 |
|  2 | a    | 2017-08-01 |
|  3 | c    | 2017-08-01 |
|  4 | a    | 2017-08-02 |
|  5 | a    | 2017-08-03 |
|  5 | b    | 2017-08-04 |
+----+------+------------+
```

My goal is create a `a_date` column where the date of all applicable rows is that of when the `type` is `a`. Like this:

```
+----+------+------------+------------+
| id | type |    date    |   a_date   |
+----+------+------------+------------+
|  1 | a    | 2017-08-01 | 2017-08-01 |
|  1 | b    | 2017-08-05 | 2017-08-01 |
|  2 | a    | 2017-08-01 | 2017-08-01 |
|  3 | c    | 2017-08-01 |            |
|  4 | a    | 2017-08-02 | 2017-08-02 |
|  5 | a    | 2017-08-03 | 2017-08-03 |
|  5 | b    | 2017-08-04 | 2017-08-03 |
+----+------+------------+------------+
```

Now to do this in R I have created a data table and tried to use a group by and have a temp column I use for the calculation:

```
test <-data.table(id = c(1,1,2,3,4,5,5), type = c("a","b","a","c","a","a","b"), 
                  date = c("2017-08-01", "2017-08-05", "2017-08-01", 
                           "2017-08-01", "2017-08-02", "2017-08-03", "2017-08-04"))
test[type == "a",temp_date := date]
test[, a_date := min(temp_date), by = c("id")]
```

What I end up with is completely different however. I have tried to separate these tables, where I have a table with just `id` and `date` and do a merge like follows:

`test <- merge(test, ids, by.x=id, by.y=id)`

This also yields results which are not desired and not the same length as the initial "test" table. (I have tried the `all.x` option)

The dataset I am actually dealing with is about 20 million rows long and gets our server quite close to its limit just by loading it in, so using a merge or having multiple copies of the table isn't really an option either.

Here is a working version using a for-loop and having a second table:

```
ids <- test[!is.na(temp_date),list(id, temp_date)]


for (i in ids[,id]){
  test[id == i, create_date := ids[id == i, temp_date]]  
}
```

I can't use this method as I am really constrained for RAM and this table is getting bigger every day. So the goal is to do it using the single data.table.

Comment: How about including `na.rm=TRUE` - `test[, a_date := min(temp_date, na.rm=TRUE), by = c("id")]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does `first(temp_date)` do the trick?

```
 > test <-data.table(id = c(1,1,2,3,4,5,5), type = c("a","b","a","c","a","a","b"), 
+                   date = c("2017-08-01", "2017-08-05", "2017-08-01", 
+                            "2017-08-01", "2017-08-02", "2017-08-03", "2017-08-04"))
> test
   id type       date
1:  1    a 2017-08-01
2:  1    b 2017-08-05
3:  2    a 2017-08-01
4:  3    c 2017-08-01
5:  4    a 2017-08-02
6:  5    a 2017-08-03
7:  5    b 2017-08-04
> test[type == "a",temp_date := date]
> test
   id type       date  temp_date
1:  1    a 2017-08-01 2017-08-01
2:  1    b 2017-08-05         NA
3:  2    a 2017-08-01 2017-08-01
4:  3    c 2017-08-01         NA
5:  4    a 2017-08-02 2017-08-02
6:  5    a 2017-08-03 2017-08-03
7:  5    b 2017-08-04         NA 
> test[, a_date := first(temp_date), by = c("id")]
   id type       date  temp_date     a_date
1:  1    a 2017-08-01 2017-08-01 2017-08-01
2:  1    b 2017-08-05         NA 2017-08-01
3:  2    a 2017-08-01 2017-08-01 2017-08-01
4:  3    c 2017-08-01         NA         NA
5:  4    a 2017-08-02 2017-08-02 2017-08-02
6:  5    a 2017-08-03 2017-08-03 2017-08-03
7:  5    b 2017-08-04         NA 2017-08-03
```

Answer (score 1):

If each `id` contains no more than one row where type is `a`, you can do this:

```
test[, a_date := date[type == 'a'], id][]

#   id type       date     a_date
#1:  1    a 2017-08-01 2017-08-01
#2:  1    b 2017-08-05 2017-08-01
#3:  2    a 2017-08-01 2017-08-01
#4:  3    c 2017-08-01         NA
#5:  4    a 2017-08-02 2017-08-02
#6:  5    a 2017-08-03 2017-08-03
#7:  5    b 2017-08-04 2017-08-03
```